# What is assumed when one write "$\nabla f$" for $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

What is assumed when one write "$\nabla f$" for $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Here is a problem I'm dealing with for weeks.

> For a fixed $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$, define $f_{a,r}:= \frac{1}{|B(a,r)|} \int_{B(a,r)} f(x) dx$. Suppose $|\nabla f|\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n), 1\leq p <n, s>n-p$, and $\limsup_{r\to 0} \frac{1}{r^s}\int_{B(a,r)} |\nabla f(x)|^p dx <\infty$. Prove that $\lim_{r\to 0} f_{a,r} \neq \infty$.

This problem was on a qualifying exam for analysis, but this problem seems somewhat related to PDE. I'm not even sure what conditions on $f$ is assumed. Is it assumed differentiable, so that $\nabla f$ is well-defined? I guessed this, but then realized that if I assume the continuity of $f$, the limit is trivially $f(a)$, so this problem would be nonsense. I'm completely lost.

What is intended and how do I prove this?

Comment: Usually one would mean a distributional derivative, for which the original f need only be measurable.

Comment: @Thompson Thank you! Could you help me with this problem? I don't know where conditions $1\leq p<n$ and $s>n-p$ can be used at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your interest, see the definition of [the weak derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_derivative). For your comment, by Lesbegue differentiation theorem, a measurable function has Lesbegue derivative almost everywhere (thus it is totally possible for $f(p)$ not equal its Lesbegue derivative)

The problem is related to [Poincare inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_inequality), which is proved in Evans (Chapter 4?). To see the optimal constant $s>n-p$, you can let $f(x)=f(r)=r^{-k}$ be a radial function, then check why $s=n-p$ gives you the desired blow-up cut-off . Mind that $B(a,r)\sim r^{n}$ by homogeneity and $dx\sim r^{n-1}drd\theta$ in all your calculations.

Comment: @Rubertos: You need to know more background. Read Evans - this is about one chapter's material.